# Linq how to cast to real object

Tags: c#, linq

I have this

```
var manager = context.ManagerInfoes.Select(m => m.Guid == managerGuid).First();
```

how can i cast it to:

```
ManagerInfo manager = context.ManagerInfoes.Select(m => m.Guid == managerGuid).First();
```

I want to get the First() real element

Comment: Cast what? Event if you're using var, it's still strongly-typed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `First()` directly instead of projecting to the `Guid` property:

```
ManagerInfo manager = context.ManagerInfoes.First(m => m.Guid == managerGuid);
```

This would be equivalent (both strongly typed) to using `var`:

```
var manager = context.ManagerInfoes.First(m => m.Guid == managerGuid);
```

In this case I find the later version more readable.

Comment: Lol nope, I wrote that before your edit, so my question is using _First() directly instead of projecting to the Guid property_ having an effect on perfs ?

Comment: @Shimrod - type of var is decided by compiler at compile time so at runtime it doesnt cause any problem

Comment: @PranayRana: I clarified my question

Comment: Nope, that's not what I ask.  My question is : Does using the predicate in `First()` have an impact on the perfs compared to using the predicate in the `Where()` and then return the `First()` element.  To write it in another form, is `context.Entity.First(e => e.Property == value)` faster than `context.Entity.Where(e => e.property == value).First()`

Comment: @Shimrod: using `First()` directly instead of projecting saves you one call (to `Select()`). In fact, it's actually redundant to call `Select` at all in this situation.

Comment: @code4life: Thanks for the answer.  I know it is redundant, but does it have a real impact, or is it just cosmetic ?  I find it easier to read when there is the `Where(...).First()`, but if there is an impact, I'd switch to the other solution (using the `First(...)` directly)

Comment: @Shimrod: You seem to be using Linq to Enitites or Linq to Sql - in this case both versions should result in the same SQL hence there is **no** performance difference. Even for Linq to Objects the perf difference is negligible.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I used link to entities syntax in my sample but my question was also for linq to objects.  However, thanks for clarifying for Linq to Entities and Linq to Sql.  Do you have some numbers concerning the impact when using Linq to Objects ?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `FirstOrDefualt` like as below

```
ManagerInfo manager = context.ManagerInfoes.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Guid == managerGuid);
if(manager!=null)
 {
          //your code
 }
```

**Advantage :** If its not able to find object for given condition return null rather than giving error as you can see above by checing null, so at runtime it doesnt break your application

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using "Where" instead of "Select" in addition to the FirstOrDefault().

Eg:

```
ManagerInfo manager = context.ManagerInfoes.Where(m => m.Guid == managerGuid).FirstOrDefault();
```

See if that doesn't help.

Comment: that would return an `IEnumerable<ManagerInfo>`. The OP is looking for a single instance of `ManagerInfo`.

Comment: That wouldn't, because of the `FirstOrDefault()` call.

Comment: Don't do it, your answer is correct, the `FistOrDefault()` returns a single instance of `ManagerInfo`

Comment: @code4life The FirstOrDefault() turns it into a ManagerInfo like Shimrod said.

Comment: @Shimrod I just went back and checked some code and saw I was right. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: @Holger: I was commenting on the original code, which didn't have the `FirstOrDefault()`, only the `Where()` (note the very first line on this answer, :D)

Answer (score -1):

Your code

```
var manager = context.ManagerInfoes.Select(m => m.Guid == managerGuid).First();
```

<strike>does not get executed. After the CLR passes this line in run time. at this time, your manager only has an expression that would, when iterated, yield the result you are looking for. 
You need to call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to get the result out of the query.</strike>

**EDIT**
Your code above is just the same as declaring manager with a strong Type. The `First()` method returns an object of type `TSource` and in your case, `TSource` is `typeof(ManagerInfo)`
    ManagerInfo manager = context.ManagerInfoes.Select(m => m.Guid == managerGuid).First();

Comment: -1: actually, you do not have to do a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`. The result of `First()` returns a **single** instance of `ManagerInfo`.